# UIToolbar tint color not working

Tags: ios, uikit

I create UIToolbar programmatically in camera overlay. I want to change its color, but it doesn't work:

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 436, 320, 44)];
[toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:226.0 green:226.0 blue:226.0 alpha:0.0];
```

[image]

The color is wrong. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add /255.0 at the red, green, blue value and it will be solved like this,

```
toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:226.0/255.0 green:226.0/255.0 blue:226.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Answer (score 4):

Further to @SergiusGee's answer, note that the `UIColor` method you are using requires values between 0.0 and 1.0 for each color element:

```
toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:226.0/255.0 green:226.0/255.0 blue:226.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

in `toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:226.0 green:226.0 blue:226.0 alpha:0.0];`

`alpha 0.0` - you make it transparent. Change it to `1.0`

Comment: @Mighter check out other people's answers, they both have the point